# Is it possible to use One UI Handler For more than One Activity?

Tags: android, handlers

Hi I want to use only single handler for more than one Activity.Can I do that ?

Comment: What exactly did you mean? A `Handler` or a `Listener`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a bit to Octavian answer, you will actually have a single Handler class but one instance per activity.

For example:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
  // Keep a weak reference to the activity owning the handler
  private WeakReference<Activity> activityRef;

  public MyHandler(Activity a) {
    this.activityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(a);
  }

  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // do your stuff here, for instance, finish the activity
    if (activityRef.get()!=null) {
      activityRef.get().finish();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  protected MyHandler handler;

  public void onCreate() {
    // This is where you'll re-use the handler code
    handler = new MyHandler(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. I thought meant Listener by saying Handler, now when I sit back and think about it I realize that there indeed exists a Handler class. :D

Comment: Well the reasoning is identical, it is only the extended class or implemented interface that will change.

Comment: Thanks Marvin and Octavian for the answer you provided. Now I want that through fragment type like one activity is master and other is slave activity.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Create a new class that implements the desired interface and instantiate it where needed.

Lets take the `OnClickListener` as an example. Create a class `ExternalClickListener`.

```
public class ExternalClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do whatever you want.
    }

}
```

Now when you want to set it on a `Button` it'd be

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new ExternalClickListener());
```

Comment: Thanks Octavian and Marvin for the answer you provided. Now I want that through fragment type like one activity is master and other is slave activity.

Answer (score -2):

Declare this Handler as a `static` and access it : `MyClass.myHandler`.

Comment: why this is not best idea. Why handler can not be static?